# Vercel cannot access Sitecore CM host as it is not public

Tags: jss

I was working on sitecore Headless with Next Js. I have created a sample application with few components and it is working fine in local. Now I tried to deploy this application to vercel.Since the sitecore host is local and is not available in public it is not accessible and deployment fails. Also in our case the QA sitecore host has SSO authentication so I assume in QA also vercel will not be able to access the sitecore host. So wanted to understand if there is any workarounds in such cases.

Comment: Did you use JSS to create the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have our Sitecore instance running locally, you need to expose your local host URL to the public internet. There are multiple reverse proxy tools to do this like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/). I have used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for the local development and it worked pretty well. Below are the steps to configure:

- Go to https://ngrok.com. Register and create a free account to get the auth token. Start the tunnel. All the steps are mentioned [here](https://ngrok.com/download). @Sebastian has also written a nice [blog](https://xtremdev.com/2021/09/09/expose-local-server-ports-to-the-internet-with-ngrok/) to explain the Ngrok set up.
- Now you need to create the tunnel for your localhost Sitecore instance. Run the below command:

```
    ngrok http --host-header=rewrite <your-sitecore-domain>:443
```

[image]

- You will get a random ngrok.io URL which is pointing to your localhost instance. You can access that URL from anywhere. It means your localhost Sitecore instance now has a public URL.
- Update the `<app-name>.config` in the NextJS application with the new hostname.

[image]

- Update Sitecore API Host in `.env` file.

```
SITECORE_API_HOST= <The URL generated by NGRock>
```

- Update the `scjssconfig.json` file

[image]

- Now push the changes to Vercel.

Answer (score 1):

Vercel is a SaaS hosting platform. You need to have a url to your GraphQL end point that is accessible over the internet. As Raman has shown, you *can* expose your local running CM instance. It is more common to have a deployed CM environment for your head application hosting to use tho.

As for your QA environment using SSO, your assumption is not correct. SSO only applies to those users logging into the admin side of Sitecore. Your Vercel app will be getting the content via the GraphQL endpoint (https://yoursitecorexmsite.com/sitecore/api/graph/edge). This endpoint uses an api key to allow access to the content. So the SSO will not make any difference.